# Git reset some changes in a file，in command line

Tags: git, git-revert

I changed something in a file, and did not use  `add` or `commit`. Some part of my changes is not necessary, how can I only reset this part. (I know how to revert the whole file, but the file has many changes and only a little change must be reset. Resetting all the changes would be a nightmare)

For some reason I can only use the command line operation git

Comment: If you did not add the file to git you must manually revert. If you have the file in git you can go back to last commit point using 'git checkout filename'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git selective revert local changes from a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109069/git-selective-revert-local-changes-from-a-file)

Comment: @kometen did you read the question? They don't want to checkout/reset over all the changes in the file, just some.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes. And OP said some files were not added which I assumed was into git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider using

```
git checkout -p
```

which allows you - for each patch of changes - to reset those changes.

Comment: Thank you! it is very effective.(but if have many patch of changes, and only one patch I want reset,I have to deal with each one??OMG....just now,13 patch changes and only 1 patch need reset   -.-!).No matter how,`git checkout -p` is very useful

Comment: I'm sorry.I'm too lazy. `git checkout -p`and`g - select a hunk to go to`.This is great!!!!!